# cannot find -lOpenNI2Orbbec. ROS Orbbec Astra camera

Tags: ros, openni, libopenni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to interface my Orbbec Astra camera using ROS (c++).

I figured out I need to use the [custom OpenNI2 by Orbbec](https://github.com/orbbec/OpenNI2).
I built it according to the instructions.

Then I tried to build [ros_astra_camera](https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_camera).
`catkin_make --pkg astra_camera` gives me `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenNI2Orbbec`

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(camera)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  image_transport
  cv_bridge
)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

 add_message_files(
   FILES
   TrackedPosition.msg
 )

 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs message_runtime
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(tracker src/tracker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tracker ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(tracker camera_generate_messages_cpp)
```

My `package.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>camera</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The camera package</description>

  <maintainer email="jeff@todo.todo">jeff</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>image_transport</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>image_transport</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_image</run_depend>

</package>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.
Please let me know if you need any additional information.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249988/cannot-find--lopenni2orbbec.-ros-orbbec-astra-camera/) by [voxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28792/voxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had this issue myself - Rename Astra OpenNI2 file to OpenNI2Orbbec in /usr/lib

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2017-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-29**:
Are you suggesting to rename the library itself?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-01-29**:
You can simply add a sym link to the OpenNI2 library file. Calling the link libOpenNI2Orbbec or there abouts

**Comment by [dwikyerl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28608/dwikyerl/) on 2017-01-29**:
There is no Astra OpenNI2 file in my /usr/lib